# In MFC, in wizard-generated WindowProc, how do I determine message sender window handle?

Tags: mfc, message, handle, sender

I have a legacy MFC application originally written in Visual C++ 6. I need to do some minor changes to it but MFC is a black box to me.

There is this apparently wizard-generated function that processes messages

```
LRESULT CMainFrame::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        ...;
  ...
  etc.
}
```

For some messages I need to get the sender window handle (which is from a different process). In Windows API a standard WindowProc has this handle as the first argument, but where is it in MFC?

Edit: Thank you Raymond and Mark. I see that I misunderstood how it works.

Comment: The first parameter to the WndProc is not the sender handle. It is the receiver handle. The sender handle is not provided, although some messages (like WM_COMMAND) have a convention of passing the sender in one of the extra parameters.

Comment: The sender of a message doesn't even need to have a window handle.  Any arbitrary code can call `SendMessage`.

Comment: The only way to know the window handle of the sender is if it is somehow encoded in the WPARAM or LPARAM parameter...such as the NMHDR* pointer in a WN_NOTIFY message.Otherwise, who knows? As Mark noted, the sender doesn't even need to have a window handle.

Answer (score 2):

This information isn't available. The first parameter in a standard window procedure is the *receiver*, not the sender. This makes sense, too, since `SendMessage` and `PostMessage` identify the receiver by window handle. The sender, on the other hand, can be any thread, including a thread that doesn't own any windows.

If you need to identify the sender of a message in the code receiving a message you will have to explicitly pass an ID along. When crossing process boundaries you're going to have to marshal any referenced memory. The system won't do that for custom messages.